# How to make a table in angular display or not

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

So im trying to get my table to display under certain circumstances and not at all. I understand the logic side of it, but i'm not quite sure where to put it in the code. Also, i haven't found a good lesson to learn *ngif. So if anyone has a good site they recommend, please share!

Ive tried plugging the *ngif right above the table itself but it just throws an error then my page won't load.

```
<tr>
    <!--AppConfig Link-->
    <td class="mapTable"><h6>AppConfig Info</h6></td>
    <td class="mapTable" colspan="3">
       <h6>AppConfig Link</h6>
         <a [href]="tomylink" target="_blank">{{referencingpage}}</a>
    <table class="nestedTable">
       <tr>
         <th class="mapTable">LOB</th>
         <th class="mapTable">Owned By</th>
       </tr>
       <tr *ngFor="myreferencepage">
         <td class="mapTable">{{myreferenceagain}}</td>
         <td class="mapTable">{{anotherreference}}</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
</tr>
```

So i removed my actual links just to show you kind of what i was going for. The header appconfiglink should display but the table "nested table" should be the conditional here. Once again, just looking to display the table if a condition has been met. And don't show anything if criteria doesnt match

Comment: Here's a good site with samples [https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: @JonRanson If i understand your problem properly than you want to create table in DOM with condition based than `<table class="nestedTable" *ngIf="variable">` and if  you get variable like this `data.variable` than first check data is after that variable like `<table class="nestedTable" *ngIf="data?.variable">`

Comment: Thank you nullptr.t hey @Abhishek. Im not sure i understand the second point you were trying to make, are you saying the some of the data could be posted if a condition is met?

Comment: @JonRansom If data like this than use second one `data={  
   "variable":{  
      "abc":1245
   }
}`

Comment: @Abhishek But where would that fit in my code already?

Answer (score 0):

Add the ngIf conditional to the table:

```
<table *ngIf="yourVariable" class="nestedTable">
```

Add that variable to your typescript file. And change its value from there according to when you want to show or hide the nested table.